# How to add a new element into a FirebaseListAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, imageview

I usually use `ArrayAdapter` and i know how to add a new element. Is there any possibility to add a new element into a `FirebaseListAdapter`? I have created a simple app in which we can add simple messages. Here is my code:

```
FirebaseListAdapter firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(this, Message.class, R.layout.message_text_view, databaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Message message, int position) {
            TextView messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text_view);
            messageTextView.setText(message.getTextMessage());
        }
    };
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

I also want to add images to the app. All i want to, is to add a new element, which is a `ImageView`, to the `FirebaseListAdapter`. The new element i want to be displayed at the end of the `ListView`. How can i do that?

Comment: A `FirebaseListAdapter` works with the given `DatabaseReference` or Query. If data is added to that `DatabaseReference`, the `FirebaseListAdapter` receives an update with the newly added data.

Comment: Ok, than the question is, how do i add a new element, which is a `ImageView`, to the my `ListView`?

Comment: This wont be possible with a `FirebaseListAdapter` as it only takes one layout. You will have to write your own one or change copy their code and add/modify some lines.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to write my own. But how can i achieve that, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from my own comment on the question:

> This wont be possible with a `FirebaseListAdapter` as it only takes one layout. You will have to write your own one or change copy their code and add/modify some lines.

If you want to change or modify some lines please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777306/7381466) on another similar question to see what to do to be able to support multiple views inside a single `ListAdapter`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This [tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row/4777306#4777306) helped me!